# Why ActualWidth and ActualHeight of an Image returns 0 after Loaded event?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

My window just contains an `Image` element such as this one,

```xml
<Image Width='255'
           Height='255'
           x:Name='img' Loaded='img_Loaded'/>
```

I want to get the values of `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` when the image is loaded but I am getting zero.

How can I get those values during runtime?

### Edit

I am trying to get those values in the `img_Loaded` handler.

```
        private void img_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int width = (int)img.ActualWidth;
            int height = (int)img.ActualHeight;
            // why zero?
        }
```

Comment: You have to load an image before those values change. Read it from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.image?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: You're right @preciousbetine. My whole point of getting those values was to create a `WriteableBitmap` and then load it in the image but I guess I could load a sample first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the image source then you will get an actualheight and actualwidth.

I tried:

```
 <Image Name="img" Height="255" Width="250" Loaded="Image_Loaded" Source="delivery3.jpg"/>
```

and

```
    private void Image_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"ActualHeight {img.ActualHeight}");
    }
```

Which gives actualheight 255 of course, because the height is set to 255.